# Want to run X with startx on :0.0 from ssh (*not* remote X forwarding)

Tags: ssh, xorg, screen

**Quick Summary:** I want to start an X session (w/ lightweight window manager) connected to the attached display (:0.0) of an Ubuntu machine, by logging into that machine from SSH. Currently I cannot do this.

**Details:**

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS machine connected to a physical display.

Using ssh, I want to log into this machine as non-privileged user, start up an X session - attached to the Ubuntu's physical display (:0.0), launch a window manager, then run synergyc to connect to my laptop's synergys instance. I do **not** want to run an X client app over SSH via X Forwarding.

When I try to run "startx", I get:

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
```

Contents of **/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config**:

```
allowed_users=console
```

My **~/.Xauthority**:

```
-rw------- 1 jpelly jpelly 0 Aug 15 12:48 .Xauthority
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: `ssh` is not a console. Also the file should be [`/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/Xwrapper.config.5.html), if I see right.

Comment: Thank you Jakuje. Updated file name. Is there a way to make ssh look like a console? I tried `ssh -t` but that didn't work.

Comment: None I would be aware of.